# Upload image and video in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I try to upload video and image in CodeIgniter simultaneously but only the image is uploaded...
My html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{$BASE_URL}multimedia/save" >
   <b>Image</b><br/>
   <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile"><br><br/>
   <b>Video</b><br/>
   <input type="file" name="video" id="video"><br><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Save"></form>
```

My controller:

```
public function save()
{
    $storage_image_path = 'path';
    if ($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]) {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], 'path' . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);

                $today_folders = date('Y') .'/'. date('m'). '/' ;


                if ( !file_exists(  $this->config->item("path") . 'big/' . $today_folders ) ){
                    $old_umask = umask(0);
                    mkdir( $this->config->item("path") . 'large/' . $today_folders, 0777, true );
                    umask($old_umask);
                }
                $filename       = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
                $filename2      = $filename;
                $extension   = end(explode(".", $filename));
                $extcnt      = strlen($extension) + 1;
                $fn_count    = strlen($filename) - $extcnt;
                $replacename = substr($filename, 0, $fn_count);
                $newfilename = $replacename . date("-d");
                $newfilename = $newfilename . '.' . $extension;
                $original_image = 'path' . $filename;
                $dimensions     = getimagesize($original_image);                   
                $width          = $dimensions[0];
                $height         = $dimensions[1];
                if ($width >= $height) {
                    $parametru = $width / 70;
                    $height    = round($height / $parametru);
                    $width     = 700;
                } else {
                    $parametru = $height / 300;
                    $width     = round($width / $parametru);
                    $height    = 300;
                }
                $config['image_library']  = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image']   = $original_image;
                $config['create_thumb']   = false;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = true;
                $config['width']          = $width;
                $config['height']         = $height;
                $config['master_dim']     = 'width';
                $config['new_image']      = $storage_image_path . '/big/' . $newfilename;
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                $this->image_lib->resize();             
                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                    exit;
                }                  
                @unlink($original_image);

            } else {
                $newfilename = "no_photo.jpg";
                $image = 0;
            }
     $this->db->query("
                INSERT INTO videos (
                        image, 
                        video) 
                VALUES (?, ?)",
                array(
                    $image,  
                    0)
            );          
   //$this->tpl->display('multimedia/add.php');

}
```

With this function I upload the image, now how to modify this method to upload and the video.Please help me guys
I make lite this:

```
 if ($_FILES["userfile1"]["name"]) 
    {
        $filename_v       = $_FILES["userfile1"]["name"];
        $filenamev_2      = $filename;
        $config['upload_path'] = 'videos/mp4/'.$filename_v;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'mov|mpeg|mp3|avi|mp4';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) 
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        }
        else 
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        }
    }
```

I don't get errors but the video doesn't upload in the specified path

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Check your php.ini setting and turn display_errors to true. Also check max upload file size

Comment: max file size I set 10000MB

Comment: I change display_errors to true but no result....no errors

Comment: Display errors should be set to on sorry my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

By default the upload routine expects the file to come from a form field called userfile, and the form must be a "multipart type:

If you would like to set your own field name simply pass its value to the do_upload function:

```
 $field_name = "some_field_name";
 $this->upload->do_upload($field_name)
```

Please read more at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

So in the above scenario for uploading the video file the following code should be there.

```
$this->upload->do_upload('video');
```